# Can I see logs in rotated files by `docker logs`?

Tags: docker, logging

We could set rotation for json-file logs of docker. If I set `max-file=3` and `max-size=10m`, there may be 2 rotated files and 1 connected file for a container. The question is, if I use `docker logs` to view the logs of this container, can I see the logs in the 2 rotated files?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like it, at least for the JSON driver.

You can test it yourself. Let's construct a case where the log files are split into two:

```
# docker run --log-driver json-file --log-opt max-size=1k --log-opt max-file=2 --name with_logs ubuntu /bin/bash -c 'echo test ; base64 /dev/urandom | head -c 1000'
# docker logs with_logs
```

Now your output looks something like this:

```
test
V9L4+Yud3l4+nyuz/J6PecuXNAcXRxiuWHv+6Lvpa34eDb/ktNTgGHxLLpFuJxmol+BCFoatZEX6
PKyqwOzot6PWnrjBwsA+CWpZUUpUMWh/ab1pF+5AYGU+n0nBudMMxehFVAzAP5PSVZdw0TvtZXGm
Trb5eHbMk1O35UF2fw7Mm8VsHEM5RPWUGO60aKODeRlPSkCogDHbGYtGVHtzyPYcL8wC64SEFTnv
(...)
```

As we can see, the `test` output is still there, even though it should have spilled into the lograted file. Let's just verify that that is indeed the case. Notice that `max-file` is set to 1:

```
# docker run --log-driver json-file --log-opt max-size=1k --log-opt max-file=1 --name without_logs ubuntu /bin/bash -c 'echo test; base64 /dev/urandom | head -c 1000'
# docker logs without_logs
yqdqW+91p2xHO58LTEzqnuwpeQncBshzm6KOutMjQh27m19D5XQ8ffIditEbgNfjc90UmxYHu1t1
arQ+3vYpzWzTSMxmxxOBTOKUKgAC36hVT3JcT+bYF2shLExdKsPA12OJFJj1gmCIF1BWhNVgsE3Z
(...)
```

As we can see, the `echo test` is not visible anymore, as the logfile does not exist anymore.

To sum it up: Yes, rotated logs are visible in docker logs

Comment: When you run the docker container with the option `max-file=3` and then do `docker logs <container_name>` you only get the content of the latest log file. you don't get to see the content of the rotated log files. There is no option in `docker logs` to access the older logs. You can see the rotation in action using 'tail -F' as in `tail -F /var/lib/docker/containers/<id>/<id>-json.log.2`

Comment: @NZD : Maybe somethings change since your comment but in my configuration`docker compose logs` or `docker logs xxx` starts with the oldest rotated log file. `*-json.9.log` for instance.

Comment: @GabrielGlenn I'm using  `Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350`. I checked this again; `docker logs <container_name>` gives me all logs, not just the most recent one. It starts with the 'head' of the oldest log file and ends with the 'tail' of the most recent log file. Yes, you are right; it seems I was wrong in my previous comment about only seeing the most recent log file.